# Custom arrowhead for mermaid class diagram

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, mermaid

I need to have a "containment" (aka anchor) icon for a UML diagram I made with mermaid in a react app.
I can't find a straightforward solution in the docs.

Is there a way to configure this?

[example of anchor icon connection I want to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdSfX.png)

Comment: could you please provide more context? do you have a code snippet?

Comment: It is currently not possible to use any custom icons for "arrowheads" in mermaid.

Comment: How about only to change the color of arrow head, @JustinGreywolf?

Comment: @dudung No, you can style the whole line, but not just the arrowhead.  I would suggest that you add this as a feature request on https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues